# Does 'java -jar' fetch transitive dependencies?

Tags: java, classpath

If I execute a jar with:

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

and `foo.jar` declares a dependency on `bar.jar` in the `Class-Path` attribute of its manifest, will the jars defined in the manifest of `bar.jar` be added to the classpath?

`MANIFEST.MF`in `foo.bar` contains:

```
Class-Path: bar.jar
```

`MANIFEST.MF`in `bar.bar` contains:

```
Class-Path: baz.jar
```

Is `baz.jar` added to the classpath when running `java -jar foo.jar` ?

Comment: Yes, it will. Manifest options are taken into account when using `-jar` switch.

Comment: @afk5min Are you sure? He is talking about **transitive** dependencies.

Comment: As I see, the question was updated and the answer was removed. I still stand by my opinion.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for an update, this seems to be [true](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath). 2nd last sentence: "If x.jar had dependencies of its own, then these would be added according to the same rules for each subsequent URL."